# Not able to view AKS logs in LogAnalytics Workspace

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

I have created a LogAnalytics workspace and attached the logs of my AKS cluster to this workspace using the instructions in the below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/view-master-logs
I am able to view the logs of my AKS cluster inside the AKS cluster blade:
[image]

I am able to view the logs inside the Default LogAnalytics workspace as well:
[image]

But I am not able to view the logs inside the LogAnalytics workspace created by me:
[image]

Following are my Diagnostics Settings for my resource group:
[image]

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Do you have a lot of different resource types hooked up to your workspace? There is a [limitation of 500 column types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/resource-logs#:~:text=Column%20limit%20in%20AzureDiagnostics,be%20dropped%20at%20ingestion%20time.) Another idea would be to create a new workspace and send logs to it to see if it's a workspace configuration issue.

Comment: It may take a few hours for the logs arriving to log analytics, please wait and check it again.

Comment: I checked after 8 hours, still could not get the logs. I dont have many resources hooked to it just the AKS cluster.

Answer (score 0):

AKS diagnostics logs are ingested into AzureDiagnostics table, please check if present there